# loader on flash template doesn't work

Tags: flash, templates, loader

I'm working on a flash template, and when i publish the site, the loader dosnt work.  I check the code in the actions menu of the `.fla` and i can't find an error. this is the code.

```
onClipEvent (load)
{
    total = _root.getBytesTotal();
}
onClipEvent (enterFrame)
{
    loaded = _root.getBytesLoaded();
    percent = int(loaded / total * 100);
    text = percent + "%";
    gotoAndStop(percent);
    if (loaded == total)
    {
        _root.gotoAndPlay(4);
    } // end if
}
```

this is the complete flash template. with the `.fla` and all the files.
http://hotfile.com/dl/93339597/35e8fdb/new_28781.zip.zip.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

1. Layer 1739 / Frame 3 --> Copy the code of the 'load0' instance
2. Layer 1739 / Frame 3 --> Clear the key frame
3. Layer 1739 / Frame 1 --> Paste the code you copied to 'load0' instance.

I don't really understand why you have the same preloaders on the same layer with the same instance name. The second one doesn't do anything there.

Hope it helps, good luck.
Rob

Comment: Hi again man, I ddid what you say (i think) but i get to errors.
I adjunt the screenshoot.

http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/4656/errorfz.png

Comment: Hey dude. You get these errors because you added them to the frame. As it is not a frame script it won't work. Click on the movieclip instance ('load0') on the stage, open the Actions Panel and add the script there (and remove it from the frame).

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm not an expert, so what this mean?
ooh i'm sorry i'll try that then.

Comment: MAN YOU ARE A GENIUS!
thank you very much!.
pd: i have another questions about this template. But i'll let you rest!! thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

OK the answer was give it by ROB (heartcode) and was:

```
Layer 1739 / Frame 3 --> Copy the code of the 'load0' instance
Layer 1739 / Frame 3 --> Clear the key frame
Layer 1739 / Frame 1 --> Paste the code you copied to 'load0' instance.
```

thanks!

Comment: Hi Nikko,first you accepted my answer which helped you to get closer with your problem, then you accepted your own answer based on mine and unaccepted mine. WTH?

Comment: was my mistake, I was too new here at that time ;). But I explicitly said that was your answer, not mine...